# worst-case complexity of algorithms

Tags: algorithm

What is the worst-case complexity of the following algorithms, where the complexity of the {sequence of code} is O(1)? so I'm looking for worse case complexity of the code written here if the rest is O(1)...

```
  a)1: for (i= 0; i < n; i++)
 2:  {sequence of code}
```

for this one I've got 0(n)

```
b) 1: int i = 0;
   2: if (i > =0)
   3:  {sequence of code}
```

I got o(1)

the rest I don't understand.

```
c) 1: for (i = 0; i < n; i++ )
   2: for (j = n; j >0; j--)
   3:  {sequence of code} 


d) 1:for (i = n; i <n+10; i++ )
   2: {sequence of code}

e) 1:for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   2: {
   3:   for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
   4:  {sequence of code}
   5:    for (k = 1; k <= 2n; k++)
   6:     {sequence of code}
   7:   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [............................algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658466/algorithms). Please edit the previous question instead of making a new one.

Comment: The issue wasn't the wording - it was the fact that you haven't appeared to have put in any work into the last few problems, and it seems as if you want us to do your homework for you.  We can check your answers, or we can give you general advice on how to tackle these problems, but please don't post a whole bunch of problems and ask for answers.  It makes us very suspicious that we're doing your coursework.

Comment: i did edit the original one but it was still closed....sorry im new to this...really sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, O(n).
2. Yes, O(1).
3. The outer loop executes N times. The inner loop executes N times for each iteration of the outer loop.
4. The loop executes a constant number (10) of times...
5. The outer sequence of code is executed inside two nested loops, just about like in `3`. The inner sequence of code is nested inside yet another loop, also executing N times for each iteration of the next loop.